# Modifying an image from a Image tag in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, readonly

I have a form in which I display a bunch of image. I would like to be able to modify this image via another executable like paint and refresh the image when I quit (via a button for example).

When I try to save the image in paint,it tells me the image is protected, which is due to the form being somehow linked to the image.

is there any way to make this work ? Any idea how to bypass the problem ?

Thanks.

Edit : Here is the strucure (heaviliy simplified) I use

```
        <ListView Style="{StaticResource BaseListView}" x:Name="LstMoulures" Grid.Column="0" Background="#00000000" SelectionMode="Single" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="White" Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="4">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,0,5" Height="200">
                            <Image x:Name="ImgPicture" Width="220" Height="195" Margin="2,5,2,2" GotFocus="ImgPicture_GotFocus" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImgPicture_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="ImgPicture_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="ImgPicture_MouseLeave">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding DessinSource}" CacheOption="OnLoad" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="test.jpg" CacheOption="OnLoad" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Also you can read the file and rewrite it to a `MemoryStream` object:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

byte[] bytArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"test.jpg");
ms.Write(bytArray, 0, bytArray.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
image.Source = bi;
```

For monitoring image changes and refreshing the image you can use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: @navid: What's the signification of `CacheOption`?  Your answer doesn't really answer the main question

Comment: look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx)

Comment: if you use `CacheOption="OnLoad"`all requests for image data are filled from the memory store.

Comment: First option seems to be working out for me. I just need to check the FileSystemWatcher for changes.

Comment: So I tried and it works for the Image CacheOption thing, and when I use a filesystemwatcher it does detect the change, but now what do I do to 'refresh' the cache ? When I try to do Lst.Items.Refresh I get a thread exception.

Comment: look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wpf/thread/976e8d89-aafd-4708-9e4f-87655a5da558)

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves my exception problem. I added the BitmapCreateOptions tag and it solved one of my problem, in which when I reopen the form it didn't show right, but I still can't update the image while in the form.